# Want a simple quick way to make ticks of a 3D plot longer

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I know there are many ways even some good packages available, but I find these methods are mostly too complex for me.

So, what's a simple quick way to make ticks of  a 3D plot (actually, a plot generated by `RegionPlot3D`) longer?

I don't care about code effiency.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can control the tick lengths in the Ticks option. E.g. Here they are set to 0.06 in one direction:

```
ticks = {#, #, {0, 0.06}} & /@ (Range[11] - 6);

RegionPlot3D[x y z < 1, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]], Mesh -> None,
 Ticks -> Table[ticks, {3}], AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, None, None}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You may use a function for `Ticks`.  This particular function comes from the `Ticks` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html), (Click on Generalizations and Extensions.)

```
ticks[min_, max_] :=  Table[If[EvenQ[i], {i, i, .06, Red}, {i, i, .02, Blue}], 
     {i, Ceiling[min], Floor[max], 1}]

Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}, Ticks -> ticks]
```

[image: ticks]

You could use a variation of it to distinguish major and minor ticks (e.g. Integer values and tenths.  This function is also straight out of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html) (Under Applications).

```
ticks[min_, max_] := 
 Join[Table[{i, Style[i, 12], {.04, 0}}, {i, Ceiling[min], 
    Floor[max]}], 
  Table[{j + .5, , {.02, 0}}, {j, Round[min], Round[max - 1], 1}]]
```

[image: ticks2]

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I couldn't resist:

```
tick = Import["http://www.salamatvet.com/images/tick-1.jpg"]; 
Plot[ Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False},
        Ticks -> {Table[{i, Labeled[i, Image[tick, ImageSize -> 30]]},
                       {i, 2, 10, 2}]}]
```

[image]

A tick is a tick, is a tick ...

Thanks to Alexey for the `AxesInFront` suggestion.

Comment: +1. Adding `Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}` makes this plot even better. ;)

Comment: @Alexey Thanks! Edited. Never heard about that Option. Where did you get it from?

Comment: See here: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/msg/11783ce8923d76b4